# Wordpress: empty post type search query results redirect instead of going to search results

Tags: wordpress, redirect, search, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm using the Search & Filter plugin to filter two custom taxonomies attached to a custom post type (subject & location). Some of my users are using the "All Subjects" & "All Locations" fields in the hopes that it will reset to the original archive page on submit. Of course, this sends Wordpress to the search results page because it results in an empty search query. That looks something like this:

http://www.example.com/?s=

Here's what makes my situation unique from the other people who simply want a message that says "no results found." Instead of letting it go to search results, I'd rather redirect my users back to the archive page of the custom post type they were on when they ran this query. Something that looks like this:

http://www.example.com/resources/

But there's another layer to the issue. I have two custom post types with two custom taxonomies. Resources and Trainings. If they're on trainings, I need them redirected to Trainings archive on an empty search query. If they're on resources, I need them redirected to resources on an empty search query.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To build this custom redirection you need to build conditional logic in INIT hook. Which checkes from which page a user is coming and redirects him to corresponding page.

```
add_action('init','custom_redirector');

function custom_redirector(){
 if (isset($_GET["s"]) and $_GET["s"]=='' and !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
 if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'resources')!==false){
  header("location: ".home_url('/resources')); exit;
 }
 elseif (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'trainings')!==false){
  header("location: ".home_url('/trainings')); exit;
  }
 }
}
```

Of course the code might need some tuning, specially in "strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'],'resources')" parts. You better know which recognizable slugs your custom post pages contain.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I realized that I was missing a certain feature built into this particular plugin. But, your answer was correct.